# JS - Sorting child objects within an object

Tags: javascript, boolean

I am trying to find if there is a way to sort objects within an object using a bool value.  I haven't been able to find anything to help, and not even sure if possible.

My object example is this:

```
{
"Music": {
    "Key": "Music",
    "Title": "Music",
    "Icon": "t-music",
    "Colour": "blue",
    "Active": false
},
"The Arts": {
    "Key": "The Arts",
    "Title": "The Arts",
    "Icon": "t-arts",
    "Colour": "blue",
    "Active": false
},
"Social": {
    "Key": "Social",
    "Title": "Social",
    "Icon": "t-social",
    "Colour": "yellow",
    "Active": true
}
```

}

Is there anyway to sort these objects within the parent object based on the "Active"  bool?

Comment: Objects do not have order

Comment: You can do `Object.keys(yourObj).sort(...)` to get the order in wich to show the keys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though objects don't have a sort order, you can organize these objects in an array based on the `Active` bool. Use [.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
var obj = {
  "Music": {
    "Key": "Music",
    "Title": "Music",
    "Icon": "t-music",
    "Colour": "blue",
    "Active": false
  },
  "The Arts": {
    "Key": "The Arts",
    "Title": "The Arts",
    "Icon": "t-arts",
    "Colour": "blue",
    "Active": true
  },
  "Social": {
    "Key": "Social",
    "Title": "Social",
    "Icon": "t-social",
    "Colour": "yellow",
    "Active": true
  }
};

var sorted = Object.keys(obj) // ["Music", "The Arts", "Social"]
  .sort(function(a, b) {
    return obj[b].Active - obj[a].Active; // Organize the category array
  })
  .map(function(category) {
    return obj[category]; // Convert array of categories to array of objects
  });
```

Comment: better `obj[b].Active - obj[a].Active` as it deals with cases where `obj[b].Active === obj[a].Active`

Answer (score 0):

The concept of order in an object doesn't exist, but you can shuffle the entries visually by turning the elements into an array, sorting it, and making a new object from that.

You can sort from a nested value by using `Array#sort` and passing it a function.

```
let arr = Object.entries(obj).sort(([key1, val1], [key2, val2]) => val2.Active)

arrayToObject = array => {
  let newObj = {}
  array.forEach(([key, val]) => {
    newObj[key] = val
  })
  return newObj
}

console.log(arrayToObject(arr))

// { Social: 
//   { Key: 'Social',
//     Title: 'Social',
//     Icon: 't-social',
//     Colour: 'yellow',
//     Active: true },
//   Music: 
//   { Key: 'Music',
//     Title: 'Music',
//     Icon: 't-music',
//     Colour: 'blue',
//     Active: false },
//   'The Arts': 
//   { Key: 'The Arts',
//     Title: 'The Arts',
//     Icon: 't-arts',
//     Colour: 'blue',
//     Active: false } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys,

I wasn't sure if objects could be sorted but never hurts to ask.

Borja's answer worked for me, but only once i used Thomas' 'obj[b].Active - obj[a].Active' in place of  '!obj[a].Active && obj[b].Active'.

I have only just seen Andrew's response and will test that out also.